# Users to log in to an Android application with Google account

Tags: android, authentication, user-accounts

I want to enable the users to log in to my application via their Google account.
I was reading topics on the web, for example [this one](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/11/10/oauth-flow-in-android-app/) where you log in with a google account using OAuth and you can access contact, calendars etc. for further use. 
I don't need this - I just want to acquire the user id after a successful user/password input. How would you suggest to do this?

Comment: Please use the new Google GData API library (http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/), as it integrates with `AccountManager`. I can think of no legitimate reason why you need a user's Google password. If you think you have such a reason, feel free to edit your question.

Comment: The whole point of `AccountManager` is so that the user doesn't have to type his\her credentials every time an app wants them and so they don't have to trust every app with their username and password.  Why do you want them to do this?

Comment: I want the application to allow the user to log in with different accounts, or for example, if I give my phone to a friend - him to be able to login with his own google account.